# what do I do if I started a bounty on accident

Tags: support, feature-request, bounty

I started a bounty and I did not mean to can I do anything to undo it.
if there is not I request that there is a way to retract the bounty on the same day.

Comment: Can you explain how you *accidentally* clicked *twice* on "Next" in the bounty dialog, *accidentally* typed the custom description [*"please explain and give a source if possible"*](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/454952/50583) into the bounty text field and then *accidentally* clicked on "Start bounty"? We do not refund bounties on request, accidental or not.

Comment: A sibling figured out my password did it. I have fixed the problem of the password.

Comment: I'm just going to be completely honest here.  It seems very odd to me that only now, 20 hours later and after answers that point out you need rare exceptions to actually reverse a bounty, you mention that a sibling figured out your password.  Your question even says that _you_ started the bounty.  This looks a lot like you are trying to make an excuse to get the bounty reversed after figuring out that it is not something that is done.

Comment: the sibling is a twin so they are and are not me

Comment: Well if they _are_ actually you, I would request you don't try lying to get your mistakes overturned.  All these edits to hide the original lack of sibling mention is screaming "dishonesty" to me.

Comment: I'm rolling this back to v3 because I feel that in that form, it's an acceptable, general question which multiple people could ask in the future.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48845777#48845777 says that you mentioned that you set up the bounty, and you were informed that it is non-refundable under any circumstances. If you are given links to official help center pages, it is not useful to post stuff on meta; it consumes space on the site's front page and time of people who read and answer.

Comment: Don't worry on it, 50 rep is not the world. Try to learn on the site, so you will be able to write good posts, these will be upvoted and so you will earn that rep back. Btw, sometimes the extra attention pays enough upvotes to get that rep back. Btw, [look what he did](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/273032/32426), he could get nearly the twice of the 500 bounty what he invested into his question :-)

Comment: @peterh Seriously? That strikes you as a constructive example to bring up in this conversation? "look, there's these other people who, after years of experience on the site, can get questions placed on HNQ which then get scores of votes"? Is that the only model of success on the site that you can offer to a newcomer? Is the antisocial behaviour of the OP there (who is now suspended because of it) the kind of thing you want to encourage?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty It was a gamble, and not a very good one. Later his similar tries weren't so successful. But here the essence of this comment was that it is not surely so bad if the OP made an accidental bounty. And I think, you know it very well.

Comment: @peterh You're raising a straw man. I have no quarrel with the core of your message - I have a problem with the specific example you chose to bring up as a representative of a "successful" bounty. Seriously, answer the question: is that really the best example you can think of?

Comment: @EmilioPisanty The bounty was successful in the sense of the net rep gain. It was not successful that it didn't lead to an accepted answer (= OP probably didn't get what he wanted). Don't mention induvidual suspensions. And, honestly, I made my example for the OP, and not for you. I hope you can forgive that I didn't optimize it for your taste.

Answer (score 11):

To be perfectly clear:

## We expect you to take responsibility for your actions.

This includes every one of your actions on this site, but in this particular context, it's worth emphasising that it includes setting bounties, allowing other people to access your account, and lying or other deceptive behaviour.

**If you set a bounty and then regretted the decision:**

There is no way to retract or refund a bounty. Moderators do have that ability, which they only use in some rare exceptions, but your case ("I made a mistake") isn't one of those exceptions. If you don't want to set bounties that you don't want to give away then don't set them.

For more information, see the FAQ in the mother meta: [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

**If you allowed someone else to access your account and you don't like what they did with it:**

This is still 100% your responsibility, and you need to pick up the tab for anything the other person did. If it's not to your liking, the only remedy is to be more careful with your account credentials, and with who you allow access to your devices, in the future.

**If it was in fact you, but you're lying to us to try to game the system:**

This is *in no way different* to lying to someone's face in real life. You're in a social situation interacting with other real human beings whom you're asking for help, in an environment where interactions are based on trust and with a basic assumption that you're acting in good faith. This means that you need to treat this exactly like you would a real-world interaction, and that antisocial behaviour is not tolerated. Users who don't stick to those rules can and do end up spending time on [the "penalty box"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/), in which your account gets suspended (for a day or a week, then increasing lengths of time) and you have no access to the site other than reading.

**More generally:**

It really sounds to me like you're not always able to take your use of the site in a calm manner, and that things sometimes get away from you. **Ask for help with this** to the people around you, be they a parent, a friend, a sibling, a therapist, a teacher, or anyone else who you trust. There is a (very low) limit to how much we can do to help you with your use of the site, and you should build a real-life support structure that you can run things by before they start to spiral.

(Or that's my take, anyway.)

Comment: If it's any consolation, the bounty in this case was 50 rep (which is the minimum), not 200 or something which could count as a 'large bounty', so a couple of good answers will help recover almost all of it. It's good that you're learning that you don't like using bounties on questions like that one, so when you have more to spend, you won't fritter it away before realizing you don't like what you're paying for.

Answer (score 8):

I want to add some more details regarding the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) part of this question... I should mention why I think adding provisions for users to cancel bounties is a terrible idea.

You should have found out how bounties work by now. There's a [featured tab](https://physics.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured) on the [front page](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) where your question is advertised. So if you want to cancel the bounty after putting it up, there's a possibility that people have already answered the question with that bounty as their motivation, or perhaps they're in the process of writing an answer. Or perhaps someone has seen your question advertised there and decided to upvote it. It's not fair for you to cancel the bounty after that: there's a possibility you've gained rep through the publicity, or someone has invested some effort.

And even if neither of those has happened in this case, it's possible that they would happen in other situations, and that makes canceling a feature which can be misused easily. Saying that there are tests to ensure that neither of these has happened before bounties are cancelled are too complicated to implement.

It's much easier to convince users to think twice before setting up bounties.